# Why do I need the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission with getExternalCacheDir() on Android Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-file, android-permissions

My app writes (and reads) cache files to the getExternalCacheDir() location. Before Android Lollipop (API 21) I've been using this permission with success:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

The maxSdkVersion is there because this permission shouldn't be needed after API v18:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

But on Android Lollipop (5.0) I'm getting an access permission like so (with my log output to show the actual path used):

```
11-19 13:01:59.257    4462-4541/com.murrayc.galaxyzoo.app E/android-galaxyzoo﹕     createCacheFile(): IOException for filename=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.murrayc.galaxyzoo.app/cache/52
    java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:941)
            at com.murrayc.galaxyzoo.app.provider.ItemsContentProvider.createCacheFile(ItemsContentProvider.java:528)
```

I see this both in the emulator and on my Nexus 4. Has something changed, or was I doing something wrong all along? I just want to access my own app's cache.

**Update:** I now see this only on my device (Nexus 4 running the standard Android 5.1.1, which has even had a fresh Android reflash since I first had this problem). I no longer see this in the emulator - of course the system images have been updated several times.

Comment: If you dont add this android:maxSdkVersion="18" properties then it work ?

Comment: Yes. I have to always request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to make this work. I wonder if there's a way to say that it's needed for <18 but >20, if it's really needed for 21 (Lollipop).

Comment: Yes as per documentation Starting in API level 19, this permission is not required to read/write files in your application-specific directories returned by getExternalFilesDir(String) and getExternalCacheDir() so we dont required this permission 19 or above API but conclusion is not work without this permission.

Comment: Hi @murrayc, I was planning to use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />` when I target my app to Masmallow. I tested in Masmallow and it works fine. Do you still see this problem in KitKat & Lollipop?

Comment: Yes, I still see this problem in Lollipop. Nothing has changed about this in Lollipop. It seems to be fixed in Marshmallow, but Lollipop is out there and we must deal with it.

Comment: If I explicitly disable the permission in Marshmallow then I cannot write to the app external cache directory. I don't get it because disabling the permission should only affect if I try to write somewhere else but not in the app directories.

Comment: Why not just add `android:maxSdkVersion="21"` for this permission?

Answer (score 5):

We've seen same behaviour on API 21 (Lollipop) on a Nexus 5:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/[package name]/cache/http/journal.tmp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
   at com.android.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache.rebuildJournal(DiskLruCache.java:346)
   at com.android.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache.open(DiskLruCache.java:239)
   at com.android.okhttp.HttpResponseCache.<init>(HttpResponseCache.java:140)
   at android.net.http.HttpResponseCache.install(HttpResponseCache.java:199)
...
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4518)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
   at libcore.io.Posix.open(Posix.java)
   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
   at com.android.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache.rebuildJournal(DiskLruCache.java:346)
   at com.android.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache.open(DiskLruCache.java:239)
   at com.android.okhttp.HttpResponseCache.<init>(HttpResponseCache.java:140)
   at android.net.http.HttpResponseCache.install(HttpResponseCache.java:199)
...
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4518)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Until Google push Android 5.0 to the AOSP we won't be able to work out if its a bug or deliberate (but undocumented) change, but I've raised this bug regardless:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81357

Adding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission prevents the above exception being thrown, but will require end user permission to upgrade existing apps. Since our app doesn't use this permission and we don't want to add it, we're falling back to using internal cache for all except KitKat devices.

As an aside, I found this an interesting background to the changes introduced in KitKat: http://www.doubleencore.com/2014/03/android-external-storage/

Comment: I appreciate the confirmation that I'm not the only one with this problem, but this seems like just a restatement of the problem rather than an answer.

Comment: @murrayc I also raised the bug with Google, although of course it was too late to fix for Lollipop as it was already in the wild. The fallback to use internal cache only was sufficient for our needs.

Comment: Yes, thanks. What sign do you have that they fixed it, too late or not?