# Permissions for getExternalCacheDir() and getCacheDir()

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

my http library is caching http responses. My current implementation to select the directory where to cache the data looks like this:

```
public static File getDiskCacheDir(Context c) {
        File dir = c.getExternalCacheDir();

        if (dir == null)
            dir = c.getCacheDir();

        return dir;
    }
```

The idea is to use `getExternalCacheDir()` as first option because I assume that there will be more space available then `getCacheDir()`. Also the official docs states that the free space in `getCacheDir()` shouldn't be too large (1 MB?)

> you should always have a reasonable maximum, such as 1 MB, for the
>   amount of space you consume with cache files, and prune those files
>   when exceeding that space.

My maximum space would be about 40 MB.

So I have two questions:

1. should I use `getExternalCacheDir()`? My apps minSDK = 14. Or should
   I use `getCacheDir()`?
2. If I should use `getExternalCacheDir()` which permissions are required? According to the official documentation:

> Starting in KITKAT, no permissions are required to read or write to
>   the returned path; it's always accessible to the calling app. This
>   only applies to paths generated for package name of the calling
>   application. To access paths belonging to other packages,
>   WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and/or READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are required.

So from my understanding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (includes permission to read, at least prior API 19) is required to work properly with `getExternalCacheDir()` prior to KitKat (API 19).

So the permission I have to set is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="19"/>
```

right?
However I see some related bugs on Lollipop like this:
[Why do I need the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission with getExternalCacheDir() on Android Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016647/why-do-i-need-the-write-external-storage-permission-with-getexternalcachedir-o)

Should I add a `try-catch` block around `getExternalCacheDir()` and use `getCacheDir()` as fallback?